# Simplest way to filter a table with js

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html

I have here a website I work at, and I have tried something like:

```
$(".camera").parent().hide(); 
$(".treicamere").parent().hide();
```

To display only apartments with 2 rooms. I know its not the best way to do that, so I'm wondering if there's a better way to sort them. Website is made in Wordpress and heres a link. You can inspect element to check formatting:

http://www.sudpark.ro/apartamente/disponibilitate/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is gonna be nasty. You ready ? :)

First, give each `p` -the ones you use as buttons- same class e.g. `p_camera`. Then add them a custom attr to get the index of them like : `data-index="1"`. After that youre set. This is your `click` function for filtering.

```
$("p.p_camera").on("click", function(){
   $("#my-table tr").not(".cf").not(":has(td[colspan=10])").hide()
                    .find("td:eq(1):contains('"+ $(this).attr("data-index") +"')").parent().show();
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2dD7c/1/)**

I can explain anything if there's something you dont understand

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a Wordpress site, you may consider using a table plugin that does exactly that, like Tabulizer for Wordpress that will allow you to filter your table rows based on column values. You can add search filter on specific columns, with different types of search filters (input box, select box) and search methods (contains, exact match, starts with, numeric range,etc) Here some ideas:

1. Create a column filter for the number of rooms. The visitor will
   select from a drop-down list the desired number of rooms
   (Nr.Camere). Same with number of balconies.
2. Create a column filter for the square meters. The visitor can find all apartments greater than 50 square meterr, less than 100 square meters or between 50 and 100 square meters.

You can also combine filtering with sorting controls.
Here is a demo http://www.tabulizer.com/index.php/support-menu/tabulizer-tips/63-sort-second-row